# USB Switch seems cause monitor brightness to fluctuate

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors

Anyone else have this issue? I have a TrendNet USB switch connected to my laptop and I use display extend to have 2 monitors. Sometimes I see the screen brightness flicker.   I reduced my frame rate to 50 but it still occurs.

Maybe can anyone recommend a better USB switch or other settings I could try?

TIA

Comment: Is your laptop connected through battery alone, or to the powersocket?

Comment: It's connected to power.

Comment: It could still be a power management thing. Can you try setting your power management to high performance, and see if that solves it?

Comment: I rechecked all my cables and made sure they were secure and the problem seems to be gone now. :)